# Why isn't Visual Studio Code autoclosing parenthesis

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

Whenever I open a parenthesis, VS Code is supposed to automatically close it but it's not doing that. I have not changed anything with my VS Code so I don't know why this would be happening.

Comment: It is due GitHub co-pilot disable it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix: Disable GitHub Copilot extension if you have it